# Android: SimpleCursorAdapter with Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

Hello everyone and thanks in advance!

I have a listview that displays a list of name from the sqlite database. What I want to know is how can I make it so that when I click on an Item in the list, it takes me to a new activity which displays the rest of the columns in the Sqlite Table?

This is the method I used to bind the listview with the cursor:

```
public void displayListView() {

    Cursor cursor = dataSource.findAll();

    String[] columns = new String[]{
            DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_NAME,
            DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_NICKNAME,
            DBHelper.CHARACTERATTRIBUTES_NOTES};
    int[] to = new int[]{
            R.id.name,
            R.id.nickname,
            R.id.notes};

    SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.character_info, cursor, columns, to, 0);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {          
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: use the last param of `onItemSelected` to read table row id

Comment: of `SQLiteDatabase.query()` ???

Comment: No, of the code in the onItemSelected method

Comment: if you want to start new activity you should call `startActivity()`